# How can I use the MatchIt function to identify the effect of a given variable (propensity score)?

Tags: r, statistics

Let's say I have a data set like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(MatchIt)

set.seed(1)
df <- data_frame(outcome = sample(c(rep("TRUE", 50), rep("FALSE", 50))), 
                 age = rnorm(100, mean = 35, sd = 15),
                 gender = sample(c(rep("MALE", 50), rep("FEMALE", 50))),
                 var1 = rnorm(100, mean = 1, sd = 0.3),
                 var2 = rnorm(100, mean = 1000, sd = 125),
                 var3 = rnorm(100, mean = 0, sd = 300))
```

I want to control for age and gender and determine the effect of vars 1, 2, and 3 on the outcome. I believe I can use the MatchIt function to control for age and gender like this:

```
match_it <- matchit(formula = outcome ~ age + gender,
                    data = df,
                    method = "nearest")
```

But once this is done, how can I determine the effect of var1 on outcome? Thanks for any help.

Comment: I suggest starting with the matching and post-matching analysis examples in the [`Matchit` package vignette](https://r.iq.harvard.edu/docs/matchit/2.4-20/matchit.pdf). If you have specific questions about coding you can ask them here. Also check out [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions) for questions about statistical methodology.

Comment: In propensity score matching, the matching model is used to predict selection into the treatment, not to predict the outcome. For example, if you had a `treatment` column in the data, the matching formula might be `treatment ~ age + gender + var1 + var2 + var3`. `matchit` would match treated and untreated subjects with similar propensity scores (i.e., similar probabilities of receiving the treatment). After matching, you would compare `outcome` for matched treated and untreated. There are a number of way to do that. See the vignette link above for examples.

Comment: [Here's another tutorial](https://sejdemyr.github.io/r-tutorials/statistics/tutorial8.html) on propensity score matching in R.